# How To Get Detail Api In Swift UI with Alamofire And Combine?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, alamofire, combine

My Network Manager With Alamofire is Like this for get all API  (**NetworkManager.swift)**

```
@Published var games = GamesDataList(results: [])
   @Published var loading = false
   private let api_url_base = "https://api.rawg.io/api/games"
```

And I want to go to navigation when I retrieve data based on ID LIst sent: **(HomeView.swift)**

```
 List(networkManager.games.results) { game in
                        NavigationLink(destination: GameDetailView(game: game)){
                            GamesRowView(game: game)
                        }
                    }
```

And if I want to switch pages, **NetworkDetail.swift** has to be like that so that the Alamofire takes away from the ID details dynamic.

```
  private func loadDetailData() {
        let parameters = "12"
        AF.request("\(api_url_detail)/\(id)",)
            .responseJSON{ response in
                guard let data = response.data else { return }
                let gamesDetail = try! JSONDecoder().decode(GamesDetail.self, from: data)
                print(gamesDetail)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.gamesDetail = gamesDetail
                    self.loading = false
            }
        }
```

And this my **GameDetailView.swift**

```
 var game: Games
    @ObservedObject var networkDetail = NetworkDetail()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            URLImage(URL(string:  "\(networkDetail.gamesDetail.background_image)")!, delay: 0.25) {proxy in
                proxy.image.resizable()
                    
                    .frame(width: 120, height: 80)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .clipped()
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Description").foregroundColor(.gray)
                Spacer()
            }
            Text(networkDetail.gamesDetail.description).lineLimit(nil)
            Spacer()
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text(game.slug), displayMode: .inline)
            .padding()
    }
```

I want when to click Item in List it will passing ID and make Request from Alamofire:

[image: View]

[image]

Please help me thanks. Right now the detailed API is still static.

Comment: Where do you track `loading`? It looks like it is not toggled. It needs more code to see workflow.

Comment: Ok I Will Edit And Add Code Flow In My Question.

Comment: It's that clear bro?.

Comment: I am not clear from your description, but I believe you wanted to pass the ID from list view to details view. If that is so, keep a @Binding property for in details view, and pass the ID from NavigationLink. 

If I understood wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Yeah like that, I was successful pass the ID but my problem is: when I go to DetaileView I want hit API based on the ID I get https://api.rawg.io/api/games/{id} from alamofire. Did you have reference?.